# find number of sides python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have used below code to find number of sides in an image but it's not giving appropriate result
import cv2

```
image = cv2.imread('sheet.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and perform contour approximation
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03 * peri, True)
    print('number of sides:',len(approx))
```

Further i want to find exact number of side in an image and length of each side in the image .
Below is the image for reference[image]

Along with this can we get the length of each side also like here we have 4 sides so the length of the respective side and the number of corners .

What if we have circular shape or arc in any shape, then how to find number of edges and it's length

Comment: try canny edges to get the outline of the object

Comment: @fmw42 tried but not getting desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV using Canny edges.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('quadrilateral.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 90, 130)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours and keep largest
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw contour
contour = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contour, [big_contour], 0, (0,0,255), 1)

# get number of vertices (sides)
peri = cv2.arcLength(big_contour, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(big_contour, 0.03 * peri, True)
print('number of sides:',len(approx))

# save results
cv2.imwrite("quadrilateral_edges.jpg", edges)
cv2.imwrite("quadrilateral_morphology.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("quadrilateral_contour.jpg", contour)

# show result
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("contour", contour)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edge image:

[image]

Morphology image (to close boundary):

[image]

Contour:

[image]

Textual Results:

```
number of sides: 4
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer can we get the length of all the 4 sides here

Comment: for x,y in zip(approx,approx[1:]):
#     print(x[0],y[0])
    d = math.sqrt((x[0][1]-y[0][1])*(x[0][1]-y[0][1]) + (x[0][0]-y[0][0])*(x[0][0]-y[0][0]))
    print('length between point:',x[0],'and', y[0],'is', d)
using above code it gives length of only 3 sides any changes for 4 side length

Comment: You have to close the figure to go back to the first point from the last one.

Comment: what if we have circular shape or arc in any shape, then how to find number of edges and it's length

Comment: hii..can u suggest the way to find the number of sides and it's length if any image have one side as circular or arc then how to calculate their length

Comment: No. I have no universal algorithm to deal with non-straight sides. Sorry.

Comment: any idea how to proceed for such cases of non-straight sides

Comment: No, I do not have any good suggestions at this time.

Comment: if u find any please suggest/edit here it will be a great help thanks