# How do I determine the number of successfully matched keypoints when using keypoint detection?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've got three images I'm trying to run object detection on. It's either 1, 2 or 3 of the same pentagon, the scale will vary but only by a few %.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried using different sections of the screen (they always appear in the same location) for `matchTemplate` i.e. the first full pentagon and the center section of the second pentagons in a loop to try and catch the correct scale, this worked some of the time but rarely and it felt a bit hacky.

Instead I've moved over to trying keypoint detection, I figured I'm likely to get roughly double the amount of matches on the second, and tripple the amount of matches on the third. Then I can go `=> x` to determine which has been found.

I've written the keypoint detection code and it works, but I can't figure out which variable to use to determine how many keypoints were found.

When I try print `good` I get this: `[<DMatch 0000018FDE162B90>, <DMatch 0000018FDE162ED0>, <DMatch 0000018FDE180150>, <DMatch 0000018FDE180210>, <DMatch 0000018FDE1807D0>, <DMatch 0000018FDE180810>, <DMatch 0000018FDE1820D0>]` which I assumed would be 7 keypoints detected, but there's vastly more being found in the `cv.imshow`.

Which variable can I use to identify the number of matched keypoints?

n.b this is functional MVP code.

```
import cv2 as cv
import win32gui, win32con, win32ui
import numpy as np
import glob

crewstars = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\images\crewstars\*.png")

def get_haystack_image():
    w, h = 1920, 1080
    hwnd = None
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (h, w, 4)
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
    img = img[...,:3]
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
    return img

def loadImages(directory):
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    # Add images to array
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        image_list.append((img, i))
    return image_list

def preProcessNeedle(image_list):
    needle_kp1_desc = []
    for i in image_list:
        img = i[0]
        orb = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=32)
        keypoint_needle, descriptors_needle = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        needle_kp1_desc.append((keypoint_needle, descriptors_needle, img))
    return needle_kp1_desc

def match_keypoints(descriptors_needle, keypoint_haystack, min_match_count): 
    orbHaystack = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=32, nfeatures=3000)
    keypoints_haystack, descriptors_haystack = orbHaystack.detectAndCompute(keypoint_haystack, None)

    FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
    index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number=6, key_size=12, multi_probe_level=1)
    search_params = dict(checks=50)

    try:
        flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
        matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors_needle, descriptors_haystack, k=2)
    except cv.error:
            return None, None, [], []
        
    good = []
    points = []

    for pair in matches:
        if len(pair) == 2:
            if pair[0].distance < 0.7*pair[1].distance:
                good.append(pair[0])

    if len(good) > min_match_count:
        for match in good:
            points.append(keypoints_haystack[match.trainIdx].pt)
    return keypoints_haystack, good, points

def keypointDetection(needle_kp1_desc):
    res = False

    # Object Detection
    for i, img in enumerate(needle_kp1_desc):
        kp1 = img[0]
        descriptors_needle = img[1]
        needle_img = img[2]

        # get an updated image of the screen & crop it  
        keypoint_haystack = get_haystack_image()
        keypoint_haystack = keypoint_haystack[170:230, 800:1200]

        kp2, matches, match_points = match_keypoints(descriptors_needle, keypoint_haystack, min_match_count=40)     
        # display the matches
        match_image = cv.drawMatches(needle_img, kp1, keypoint_haystack, kp2, matches, None)
        cv.imshow('Keypoint Search', match_image)
        cv.moveWindow("Keypoint Search",1940,30)
        cv.waitKey(0)       

        if match_points:
            cv.imshow('Keypoint Search', match_image)
            cv.waitKey(0)       
            res = True
            break      
    return res

while True:
    crewstarsdir = loadImages(crewstars)
    needle_kp1_desc = preProcessNeedle(crewstarsdir) 
    if keypointDetection(needle_kp1_desc):
        pass
```

Comment: The matching itself can't tell whether for one keypoint it was successful nor not. Indicators are the descriptor distance and a nn-ratio-test, both not able to distinguish perfectly. A better way is to use perspective homography estimstion with a RANSAC from all the (remainimg) matches. The inlier and outlier of the RANSAC tell you which keypoints were correctly matched snd support the found homography.

Comment: I would've thought `drawMatches` is basing it's detections on a match, isn't there a way to simply count those identifications?

Comment: sure you can just count the number of DMatch entries, but how do you distinguish whether matching for that point was "successful"?

Comment: in your code, you can just check the size of `good` which is the number of matches you accept.

Comment: oh, I wrongly thought a DMatch *was* a successful match, although reading now it's saying it's "DMatch object only stores the indices of matched keypoints, their distance and the index of the image" so that's really not all that useful I think.

Comment: for pixel art, you shouldn't use feature matching. use matchTemplate with SQ_DIFF*

Comment: You are using a nearest neighbor ratio threshold, so in some way all those matches are "successful" (but with some mistakes). See my first comment about what else can be done.

Comment: Thanks both, I've checked `good` with `len` which is what I was missing before and it's very not right for numerous reasons I doubt I need to explain to both of you! I looked at perspective homography and it's way out above my skill level, I'd need to learn quite a bit to scratch the surface there. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874570/find-number-of-sides-python might work as it's always going to be 3-5-15 sides.